# No IUserTokenProvider is registered error after update identity 1 to 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have updated identity in my project to version 2 and in `ForgotPassword` action in `AccountController` i receive `No IUserTokenProvider is registered error` in this line:

```
 string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

then i implement `IUserTokenProvider` interface based on [this](http://eliot-jones.com/2014/10/asp-identity-2-0-password-reset) and in `IdentityConfig` i use :

```
 public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
 {
     var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
     //other code 
     manager.UserTokenProvider = new MyUserTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>();        
     return manager;
 }
```

but the same error occured again.
then i initialize `manager.UserTokenProvider` in `ForgotPassword` action and every thing worked fine.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return View("error message");
                }

                UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new MyUserTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>();

                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution. every thing was implemented truly in identityconfig. the problem was in `AccountController`. i had made an new object of `UserManager` and did not used of injected object of `userManager` :

```
public AccountController() 
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
                    {
    _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
                {
                    UserManager = userManager;
                }

                public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

in new version :

```
public AccountController()
        {
        }
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

this work fine now.

Comment: How does MyUserTokenProvider look like?